# How to get out of a while loop in tornado

Tags: python, tornado

The server.py uses the Python Web Framework, tornado.

I want to create a program that sends the stock selected from the pull-down menu in client.html to server.py, retrieves the corresponding stock from SQL, and sends it back to client.html.

Since the SQL is updated at any time, I used to use def on_message as in (*1) while True to update the SQL at any time when there is one issue.

However, I saw the note in (*2), so I was wondering if anyone can help me figure out how to disconnect the previous loop when I select another stock in the pull-down menu, and send the update information as needed in the new stock to client.html?

(*1)

```
import psycopg2, os, pandas as pd, time, json, random
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop

class RealTimeDataHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print ('Session Opened. IP:' + self.request.remote_ip)
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname='postgres',
            user='postgres',
            password=os.environ.get('PostgreSQL_PASS'),
            host='localhost',
        )
        self.cur = conn.cursor()

        self.ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    def get_data_from_sql(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM public.random_time_multi")
        m = self.cur.fetchall()
        column_names = [desc[0] for desc in self.cur.description]
        data = pd.DataFrame(m, columns=column_names)
        return data

    def on_message(self, message):
        column_name = json.loads(message)['symbol']
        while True:
            data = self.get_data_from_sql()
            message = json.dumps(data[column_name].to_dict())
            self.write_message(message)
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_close(self):
        print("Session closed")
        self.cur.close()
        self.ioloop.stop()
        
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

def stop_tornado():
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().stop()

app = tornado.web.Application([(r"/ws/display", RealTimeDataHandler)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.listen(8080)
    try:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    except:
        print("KeyboardInterrupt received. Stopping Tornado.")
        stop_tornado()
```

(*2)
If an infinite loop (while true, etc.) is executed in the on_message method, a new message cannot be received. This is because while the infinite loop is running, the on_message method is blocked and the event loop for processing new messages is not executed.

Comment: hi @LeonhardThird , i think the solution is to use threads running concurrently 
and manage the data/resources between threads .

Comment: What effect are you looking to achieve with the loop?  If you are looking to get the "latest" data, why not do the query when you get the request?  If you are looking to get recent data but not flood your database why not use a cache decorator?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by using [`tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback) and doing the following

```
import psycopg2, os, pandas as pd, time, json, random
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop

class RealTimeDataHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print ('Session Opened. IP:' + self.request.remote_ip)
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname='postgres',
            user='postgres',
            password=os.environ.get('PostgreSQL_PASS'),
            host='localhost',
        )
        self.cur = conn.cursor()

        self.column_name = None

        self.periodic_callback = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(self.send_data_to_client, 5000)    # 5000は5000[ms]
        self.periodic_callback.start()

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.column_name = json.loads(message)['symbol']
        print('RecieveMessage of %s' % self.column_name)

    def get_data_from_sql(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM public.random_time_multi")
        m = self.cur.fetchall()
        column_names = [desc[0] for desc in self.cur.description]
        data = pd.DataFrame(m, columns=column_names)
        return data

    def send_data_to_client(self):
        print('send data of %s' % self.column_name)
        if self.column_name:
            data = self.get_data_from_sql()
            message = json.dumps(data[['unix_time', self.column_name]].to_dict())
            self.write_message(message)

    def on_close(self):
        print("Session closed")
        self.cur.close()
        self.periodic_callback.stop()
        
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

def stop_tornado():
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().stop()

app = tornado.web.Application([(r"/ws/display", RealTimeDataHandler)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.listen(8080)
    try:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    except:
        print("KeyboardInterrupt received. Stopping Tornado.")
        stop_tornado()
```